# Embedding a launch file with a parameter

Tags: ros, roslaunch, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two ros launch files, A.launch and B.launch.

I want B.launch to be included in A.launch like that:

A.launch:

```
<launch>
    <node name="rosbridge" pkg="rosbridge" type="rosbridge.py" />
    <include file="$(find some_package_name)/launch/B.launch">
    </include>
    ...
</launch>
```

Works pretty nice. However, it becomes a problem, as soon as there is a parameter necessary in B.launch:

B.launch:

```
<launch>
    <node name="$(arg START_NODE_NAME)" pkg="some_package_name" type="some_type">
    </node>
</launch>
```

I tried to use the following tag in A.launch:

```
<launch>
    <node name="rosbridge" pkg="rosbridge" type="rosbridge.py" />
    <include file="$(find some_package_name)/launch/B.launch">
            <arg name="START_NODE_NAME" value="goal_server" />-->
    </include>
    ...
</launch>
```

but that didn't work out either.

Is that scenario just not possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62949/embedding-a-launch-file-with-a-parameter/) by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're on the right track. You only need to define the arg in B.launch, i.e. add

```
<arg name="START_NODE_NAME" />
```

to the top of B.launch.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on 2013-05-23**:
works, thanks!